# How To: PHP Character Counting?

Tags: php, forms, output

I hope that I am not asking a question, which was already asked in here, but I used the search for quite some time as well as google and couldn't find anything that helped me.

What I am searching for a php function, to count the amount of characters written into a textarea, after a textarea in a form was submitted.

So e.g. we have a textarea, where you have to enter a description of your car. Now when you click on the submit button, the next page should show you: Your description for your car is 120 characters long.

I only found lots of jquery scripts, which count the characters with an immediate output on the same page, but that's not what I am looking for.

Comment: Use `strlen()` to count the characters

Comment: You are asking for the whole script, this is not a question

Comment: Im sorry, i didnt mean to ask for the whole script. Perrys answer already helps me.

Comment: Or mb_strlen depending if you have special chars

Comment: To save time in the future just `google 'php get length of a string'` and most of the time you will get a link to php.net/manual/ :)

Comment: So just to clarify strlen() doesnt count special characters, but mb_strlen does?

Comment: PHP has a built in function called [strlen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php). I'm not sure if you need help with the HTML form submission as well but the full PHP code will be `<?php echo 'Your description for your car is '.strlen($_POST['textarea_name_attribute']).' characters long';`

Comment: Take time too get into `encoding in PHP`.  `strlen` works with `latin` and mb_strlen works with `utf8`. That has all to do with how many bytes a char needs. e.g. `ä` takes more bytes than `a`.

Answer (score 0):

If on your form you had:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
    <textarea name="my_car"></textarea>`
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then on process.php you could count the number of characters submitted with `strlen()`.

```
<?php
    $length = strlen($_POST['my_car']);
    echo "Your description for your car was $length characters long.";
?>
```

You may want to do some trimming and cleanup of the POST variable before counting, but that's the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to count bytes or characters? Depending on the character encoding they are not the same thing -- emoji for example take more than 1 byte.

Use `strlen($_REQUEST['descriptionFieldName'])` to get the number of bytes.

Use `mb_strlen($_REQUEST['descriptionFieldName'], 'UTF-8')` to get the number of characters in the most common character encoding (UTF-8). The character encoding should match the encoding defined in the `<meta charset="...">` in the `<head>` of your html document.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude spaces from the string length counting you can do the following:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <textarea name="my_car"></textarea>`
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then the PHP:

```
<?php
$str=$_POST['my_car'];
$str = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z]/","",$str);
echo strlen($str);
?>
```